# RLMException, Migration is required for object type

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an object `NotSureItem` in which I have three properties `title` whose name is renamed from `text` and `textDescription` which I had added later and a `dateTime` property. Now when I am going to run my app it crashes when I want to add something to these properties. It shows following statements.

```
'Migration is required for object type 'NotSureItem' due to the following errors:
- Property 'text' is missing from latest object model.
- Property 'title' has been added to latest object model.
- Property 'textDescription' has been added to latest object model.'
```

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import Realm

class NotSureItem: RLMObject {
    dynamic var title = ""   // renamed from 'text'
    dynamic var textDescription = "" // added afterwards
    dynamic var dateTime = NSDate()
}
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

**As long as you have not released your app** you can simply delete your app and run it again.

Everytime you change properties on your Realm objects your existing database becomes incompatible to the new one.

As long as you are still in the developing stage you can simply delete the app from the simulator / device and start it again.

**Later when your app has been released** and you change properties on your objects you have to implement a migration to the new database version.

To actually perform a migration you implement a Realm migration block. Typically you would add the block to `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`:

```
var configuration = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 1,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {

            // if just the name of your model's property changed you can do this 
            migration.renameProperty(onType: NotSureItem.className(), from: "text", to: "title")

            // if you want to fill a new property with some values you have to enumerate
            // the existing objects and set the new value
            migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: NotSureItem.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                let text = oldObject!["text"] as! String
                newObject!["textDescription"] = "The title is \(text)"
            }

            // if you added a new property or removed a property you don't
            // have to do anything because Realm automatically detects that
        }
    }
)
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = configuration

// opening the Realm file now makes sure that the migration is performed
let realm = try! Realm()
```

Whenever your scheme changes your have to increase the `schemaVersion` in the migration block and update the needed migration within the block.

Comment: It is the correct answer. Just someone downvoted it. Could you please accept the answer if it workied for you, so this is marked as a correct answer?

Comment: I want to ask you one more thing, my data is successfully saved in realm file but its empty in my table view when I run my app again.@joern

Comment: Could you post a new question for that? To be able to help you on this I would need to see the parts of your code that are relevant (How, where and when you are retrieving the data). That's not really working in a comment thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277061/swift-realm-property-has-been-added-to-latest-object-model-migration

Comment: This answer should be removed as incorrect. You should provide guideline to migration instead of this workaround of problem.

Comment: This answer works for a development environment but is not acceptable for production. We cannot ask all app users to uninstall and reinstall the app after every update. Users should be able to move the existing data to the updated app (that is what migration stands for).

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. I updated my answer to include an example for a migration block that OP would need.

Comment: Should I worried about that this error would not occur when app goes for deployment and user access the updated realm data? as deleting the app in development version is the only solution i have. hope this would not happen in production version. Any Suggestion?

Comment: @VinayakPal If you change your Realm objects AFTER you released your app you **must** use the migration block, otherwise the app crashes!

Comment: @joern i added some objects in one of my realm class. what should I need to added in migration block for those objects?

Comment: @VinayakPal Please have a look at the migration code example in my answer. The comments explain what you have to do. If you just added new objects or properties you shouldn't have to do anything. But if you are getting the error message in debug mode you have to use migration or your app will crash

Comment: @joern I applied your migaration code block in my project but still I'm getting migration error during runtime

Comment: @VinayakPal Can you please open a new question for your issue? It‘s hard to see what causes the problem without seeing your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184793/discussion-between-vinayak-pal-and-joern).

Answer (score 26):

Delete the app and re-install is not a good practice. We should incorporate some migration steps during development from the first time we encounter migration need. The link given by SilentDirge is good: [realm migration document](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations), which gives good examples for handling different situations.

For a minimum migration task, the following code snippet from the above link can automatically do the migration and is to be used with AppDelegate's `disFinishLaunchWithOptions` method:

```js
let config = Realm.Configuration(
  // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
  // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
  schemaVersion: 1,

  // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
  // a schema version lower than the one set above
  migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
    // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
    if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
      // Nothing to do!
      // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
      // And will update the schema on disk automatically
    }
  })

// Tell Realm to use this new configuration object for the default Realm
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

// Now that we've told Realm how to handle the schema change, opening the file
// will automatically perform the migration
let _ = try! Realm()
```

Comment: I'm a total newbie in Realm and developing ReactNative and facing this issues. I'm wondering if adding this code is to let Realm automatically detect the difference? No further actions needed?

Comment: @Isaac you need to bump the `schemaVersion` every time your Realm objects have new or deleted fields.

Comment: it was useful for me. thank @CodeBrew

Answer (score 11):

Below code is working for me

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{  
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration    defaultConfiguration];
 config.schemaVersion = 2;
config.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t  oldSchemaVersion) {
  // The enumerateObjects:block: method iterates
  // over every 'Person' object stored in the Realm file
  [migration enumerateObjects:Person.className
                    block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {
    // Add the 'fullName' property only to Realms with a schema version of 0
    if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
      newObject[@"fullName"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                            oldObject[@"firstName"],
                            oldObject[@"lastName"]];
    }

    // Add the 'email' property to Realms with a schema version of 0 or 1
    if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
     newObject[@"email"] = @"";
    }
  }];
 };
[RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];

// now that we have updated the schema version and provided a migration block,
// opening an outdated Realm will automatically perform the migration and
// opening the Realm will succeed
[RLMRealm defaultRealm];

return YES;
}
```

More info : https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#getting-started

Answer (score 5):

## Just increment the schema version

#### Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties

```
var config = Realm.Configuration(
            // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
            // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
            schemaVersion: 2,
            
            // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
            // a schema version lower than the one set above
            migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
                if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                    // Nothing to do!
                    // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
                    // And will update the schema on disk automatically
                }
        })
        
               
        do{
            realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
            
            print("Database Path : \(config.fileURL!)")
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your modified database is no longer compatible with the saved database which is why a migration is required. Your options are to delete the old database file and start fresh (works great if you are in the initial dev phase), or if you are live, do the migration.

You do this by defining a schema version and providing a database migration 'script' within your Realm configuration. The entire process is documented here (along with code samples): [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations)

Answer (score 2):

You can erase database on launch like this:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:[RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration].fileURL error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error even after incrementing the schemaVersion. Then do a **double-check**. Whether **you are calling any Realm object before updating the schema version in App Delegate**.

In My case, I was trying to access a Realm Object in App Delegate before that code migration statement is executed.

**Always write the migration code in the first line of App Delegate (DidfinishLaunchingWithOptions) to be on a safer side.**

Answer (score 0):

You make 'Any" change to your realm, you will get the migration error.

To fix this:

1. Close Xcode
2. run this code in your terminal:
   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
3. Re-open Xcode and build.
4. Problem is fixed
   This will remove the Xcode data that is creating the error.

Every time you change something that has to do with 'Realm", do this and you will be back up and running.